# Store static values into .net app

Tags: c#, static

Is there any good practice to store static values in .net application?
I don't want to store every static values into their class which these values are common.
Do you know any good practices about this usage?

Edit:
For eg. I have Person, Task classes and both these classes will use same static variables like let's say TATA. TATA variable will carry "TOTO" but later when I want to chance this value "TITI" I don't want to find all TATA static variables in every class and change. I just want to use TATA variable in only one place and use in every classes.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?  You can put `static` variables wherever you want.

Comment: `"I don't want to find all TATA static variables in every class and change."` - Well, why would you have more than one of any given variable?  If you're repeating code, that's a problem in and of itself and unrelated to whether or not anything is `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is const. Just create some kind of global static class with global consts, like:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public const int VALUE = 1;
}
```

And when you want to call this value do just:

```
int i = Globals.VALUE;
```

Some say that you shouldn't have such a class in your project and if you have to, it means that you might have done some errors while designing you project. But, to be honest, sometimes it's the simplest and best way to do some things.